# Datatables Row Expand/Detail with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables to display an output from a query and I'm not using Ajax. I'm trying to use the row details feature of datatables as on this example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

The result I'm getting from the query its assigned to arrays and displaying them as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" >  

                <div class="table-responsive" >  
                     <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">  
                          <thead style="background-color: #8BA8CA;"> 

                <tr>

                    <th class="text-align-center">Job Number</th>
                    <th class="text-align-center">SC</th>
                    <th class="text-align-center">Circuit</th>
                    <th class="text-align-center">Job Type</th>
                    <th class="text-align-center">Duration(mins)</th>

                </tr> </thead>
<tbody>
                  <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($NUM_1); $i++)
                { 
                ?>

                <tr>

                <td align="center">
                        <label class="text-align-center">                           
                            <?php echo $NUM_1[$i]; ?>
                        </label></a>

                    </td>
                <td align="center">
                        <label class="text-align-center">
                            <?php echo $SC[$i]; ?>
                        </label>

                    </td> 
                    <td align="center">
                        <label class="text-align-center">
                            <?php echo $CIRCUIT[$i]; ?>
                        </label>

                    </td> 
                <td align="center">
                        <label class="text-align-center">
                            <?php echo $JOB_TYPE[$i]; ?>
                        </label>

                    </td>
                <td align="center">
                        <label class="text-align-center">
                            <?php echo $DURATION_MINUTES[$i]; ?>
                        </label>

                    </td> <?}?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
       var dataTables = $('#myTable').DataTable({
          fixedHeader: true,
        select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
        order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        aLengthMenu: [[100, 200, 500, -1], [100, 200, 500, "All"]],
        pageLength: 200,rowGroup: {
                dataSrc: 1
            },


        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-1'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-5'f>>" +
          "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
          "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",

    buttons: [
      {extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Export to Excel'},

                'print'
    ]

    });
</script>

<!--This script applies the column filtering-->
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {


    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#myTable tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+' " style="font-size:11px;"/>' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();


    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );



} );
</script>
```

The example shown in the link (https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) is using Ajax data with Javascript but my data and variables are in PHP.
How I can work this with my PHP and get it work with the Javascript datatable

Comment: Would result are you currently getting? I see you linked the Datatables to your HTML table (#myTable), so that should work. Another problem could be that your JS script is called to early. Make sure to put the Datatables definition inside the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Fixed the ready function. Thanks for the notice. I'm getting the table already but I need to implement the row detailed information feature in it as I'm using  PHP not Ajax. What needs to be added/edited to my code as from this example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: You'll need a way to distinguish child rows from main rows.  Then, use JS / jQuery to toggle visibility of the child rows when the main row is clicked.  You can optionally toggle an image on the main row when the child visibility is toggled.  The exact code for this implementation is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.  You should write the code and then come back with more specific questions.